# Возможна ли передача вируса из одной учётной записи другой?

Tags: windows, вирусы

На своём компьютере я собираюсь использовать одну учётную запись только для взаимодействия с торрентом и пиратским ПО(учётка будет эдакой зоной отчуждения),а вторую для лицензированного ПО. Рабочая ли это схема? Возможна ли передача вируса из одной учётной записи другой? И если есть нюансы, то пожалуйста опишите поподробнее.

Comment: Нет, схема не рабочая. Вирус поразит какой-нибудь системный файл. Все учётные записи его немедленно получат. Заведите виртуальную машину.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а как он поразит системный файл без прав администратора?

Comment: @andreymal, в идеальном мире никак. В реальном есть "privilege escalation attacks".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в реальном можно и из виртуальной машины сбежать, если постараться

Comment: @andreymal, чтобы сбежать из виртуальной машины надо атаковать пару guest/host. Периметр для атаки намного меньше. Каждый первый вирус проникнув на машину пытается поднять свои права используя огромный периметр в котором дырки могут быть в любом приложении. Не говоря о том что виртуальная машина мгновенно откатывается назад уменьшая время атаки.